# how to analyze the address?

Tags: python, django

please help configure urls.py

root page of my site

```
mysite.com/
```

contains several references to the child pages

```
mysite.com/page1/
mysite.com/page2/
mysite.com/page3/
```

urls.py I set as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('',
url (r '^ blog /', include ('blog.urls')),
url (r '^ admin /', include (admin.site.urls)),
    url (r '^ (. *) /', 'mysite.views.base_page', name = 'base_page'),
    url (r '^ $', 'mysite.views.base_page', name = 'base_page'),
)
```

view.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import loader, RequestContext


def base_page(request):
    t = loader.get_template('base_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

as a result when I turn at mysite.com/page1/ I get the following error message:

> ```
> base_page () takes one positional argument but were given 2
> Exception Type: TypeError
> Exception Value:
> base_page () takes one positional argument but were given 2
> Exception Location: C: \ Python33 \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ core \ handlers \ base.py in get_response, line 114
> ```

ps
remarkable that so do not get the above error:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    #url(r'^(.*)/', 'mysite.views.base_page', name='base_page'),
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.base_page', name='base_page'), 
)
```

Comment: Show the code of view function or class. The signature is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error explains itself, there is too much arguments.

```
base_page () takes one positional argument but were given 2
```

When you load page `mysite.com/page1/`, django search the url patterns one by one and load the the first one that matches, in this case, this following line:

```
url(r'^(.*)/', 'mysite.views.base_page', name='base_page'),
```

The problem is how django pass arguments to views.  According to the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/):

#### How Django processes a request

When a user requests a page from your Django-powered site, this is the algorithm the system follows to determine which Python code to execute:

1. Django determines the root URLconf module to use. Ordinarily, this is the value of the ROOT_URLCONF setting, but if the incoming HttpRequest object has an attribute called urlconf (set by middleware request processing), its value will be used in place of the ROOT_URLCONF setting.
2. Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable
   urlpatterns. This should be a Python list, in the format returned by
   the function django.conf.urls.patterns().
3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.
4. Once one of the regexes matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a simple Python function (or a class based view). **The view gets passed the following arguments: An instance of HttpRequest. If the matched regular expression returned no named groups, then the matches from the regular expression are provided as positional arguments.** The keyword arguments are made up of any named groups matched by the regular expression, overridden by any arguments specified in the optional kwargs argument to django.conf.urls.url().
5. If no regex matches, or if an exception is raised during any point in this process, Django invokes an appropriate error-handling view. See Error handling below.

In your case, Django would call the function `mysite.views.base_page(request, 'page1')`, the error occurs.